# Find recently moved file in a directory

Tags: java

I have scenario where I need to detect recently moved file in a directory. Option are available which says check the last modified date then we can pick up.

But in my case even if the file comes there is a possibility that its modified date is older than already existing files.

So Is there anything we could write any code snippet who could just detects the latest moved file ? Just based on movements but not any last modified date.

Ideas...?

EDIT:

Operating System using: Windows

Comment: Can you expect the program to be executed each time a file is moved? If so, persist a list of files present in the directory at each execution and check it the next time.

Comment: Also, you should probably mention which OS your code will target.

Comment: @Aaron, I run my program once in a day. So I want my program to pick  moved file on that day only.

Comment: Have a file contain the list of the directory's content. Each time you run your program, take the difference between the current content and the one listed in the file : that's your newly added files. Then overwrite the file with the current directory content.

Comment: @Aaron, That would be bad solution if the number of files are more. And looking for difference at every run not a good idea I guess...!!

Comment: Well I mean it's not great, but for something that must only run once a day that shouldn't be a problem. I wouldn't expect an execution time of more than a few seconds or a working file of more than 50KB, and I'm assuming a thousand files here. If you have harsher conditions you should state them. Of course if you could rely on file metadata that would be much better, but as you realized moving files don't change their modification date...

Comment: Another option would be to modify what moves them so that it updates their modification date or sets whatever visible info on them that you can pick up, e.g. suffix their name with `.new` and let your program rename them once it has detected them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep track of what is going on within one or more specific directories (folders) then use Java's **[Watch Service API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#try)** which is part of the **java.nio.file** package.

This API can detect when a file is moved, copied, or created within the specified directory. Even when a file is edited, modified, or deleted from within the very same directory.

Read the information within the supplied Oracle link above and try the **[demo application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java)** which can be downloaded (copied) from within the **Try It Out** section. I think it's just what you may be looking for.